# Force latexmk to rebuild a specific .tex file

Tags: latexmk, shell-escape

A LaTeX file (rebuild.tex) includes external \write18 commands to rebuild another (a.tex) based on external data sources (e.g., SQL).

However, since rebuild.tex doesn't change, latexmk won't rebuild it, which mean the external commands won't run and a.tex won't be updated.

Is it possible to tell latemk to always rebuild a specific .tex file (rebuild.tex)?

Comment: For `latexmk` the `-g` option will force compilation

Comment: Ideally, you'd like to have the dependency on the external data source files detected by latexmk, so it would do a rebuild automatically if the data source files change.  You could get inspiration from the files in the example_rcfiles in the latexmk distribution.

Comment: Thanks @deleif, but this re-compiles everything (a large project), taking a long time.